# What circuit creates this waveform?

Tags: circuit-design, waveform

[image]

Hi :) I was wondering if I could have some help with figuring out what circuit would yield this waveform. I'm trying to make sure that 1 and 3 can only be high if 2 is high when they are triggered. I'm unsure of how to:

a) hold 2 high and have it drop when the signal from 1 or 3 ends (it will be a blip from a button)

and

b) have 1 and 3 be ignored when 2 is not high

I was thinking about potentially using a clocked t-flip-flop but I have minimal experience in pretty much all things EE.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: A microcontroller can do that

Comment: @PlasmaHH What would I be programming it to do? I have a National Instruments DAQ system I could use if you think that may be applicable.

Comment: In your 4th time period you seem to have 3 half low & half high. Should that be split into 2 time periods with 3 low in one and high in the other and 2 high for both of them?

Comment: @MadisonLilly: Welcome to SE. You could have cropped your photo for us. ;^) I think you should have six waveforms on your sketch. IN1, OUT1, IN2, OUT2, IN3 and OUT3. If you do this it will help clarify your thinking. You then should be able to do what you want with set/reset latch, inverters and AND gates.

Comment: @brhans yes, oops :/ thanks for spotting that. and thanks transistor, I'll crop next time and try the ins and outs. Can't believe I didn't think to include those :)

Comment: @MadisonLilly: There's a schematic editor button on the editor toolbar. You can create a simple timing diagram with the line tool and the text tool.

Comment: @transistor will do! This is such a nice website! You all are so helpful already.

Comment: What causes signal 2 to go high?

Comment: Which are inputs, which are outputs?

Answer (score 1):

As a first try, I recommend you use 2 AND, 1 OR, and an edge-triggered D type flip-flop.  Connect signals 1 and 2 to input of one AND, 2 and 3 to inputs of other AND.  Connect the outputs of the AND gates to inputs of OR gate.  Connect output of OR gate to reset pin of flip-flop.  Connect output of flip-flop to set pin of flip-flop and to the signal 2 inputs of the AND gates. Connect the clk signal to the flip-flop.